# Liferay Search Container Row Processing

Tags: search, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am getting my Model data from JSON.

I have implemented the searchContainer successfully, however I want to access the deep object elements

```
<liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="${searchRecordsContainer}"  >
    <!-- In order to get the total results and also to display no. of data -->  
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%=searchContainer.getTotal() %>" results="<%=searchContainer.getResults() %>" />
    <!-- Display Row with First Name,Last Name,ScreenName and Description as columns -->
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row  className="com.demo.Records" >
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Record Id" property="recordId"/>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Record Value" property="attributes.value('SOME_KEY')"/>    //how to do this??
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <!-- Iterating the Results -->
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator/>
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Model of the Records

```
public class Records {
    private Attributes attributes;
    private String recordId;
}
public class Attributes {
    private List<Entry> entry;
    public String getValue(String key) {
        if (this.entry == null || this.entry.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        for (Entry record : this.entry) {
            if (record.getKey() != null && record.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                return record.getValue();
            }
        }
        return "";
     }

}
public class Entry {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

`So how do I call that specific method by passing some STRING value to get my desired value?`

One more point, `I want to do some server side processing, when user clicks on nextPage or changes recordsPerPage or Sorting, how do I handle that?` Any example is much helpful

Comment: Can't you write scriplet ? for example : ` <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Record Value"><%=attributes.getValue(key)%></liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>`

Comment: @PankajKathiriya, probably you can't access the element such a way.

Comment: You can have modelVar record attribute for row. Ans use it like record.getAttributes().getValue(key)

Comment: @PankajKathiriya, could you post the same as answer, I will mark it as answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have modelVar record attribute for row.

And use it like record.getAttributes().getValue(key)

Regards,